# worker process run code of master process

Tags: node.js, process

When I change the test.js, the `console.log("Source code change, start to restart worker one by one")` run 3 times?. I have one master process, so it should be one time

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var fs      = require('fs');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    fs.watch('./config/test.js', function(curr, prev) {
        console.log("Source code change, start to restart worker one by one");
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./config/config.js')];
    })

}else{
    var config = require('./config/test.js')
}
```

Comment: I doubt. What happens if you change your three workers to 10? I assume your modification process changes the file 3 times...

Comment: @CFrei, Yes, I change to 10 workers, I still get 3. So what is the problem you find out?

Comment: @CFrei, My nodejs server run on EC2 of Amazon and I use WinSCP to remote modifiaction test.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your watchdog (`fs.watch`) is triggered three times, maybe because you write three blocks of data? Maybe it would trigger more often when the file becomes bigger? (Maybe WinSCP it truncating the file before writing?)

I assume you want to trigger only when the file is uploaded completely?

Unfortunately you can't catch the message `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` from `inotify(..)`.

So do something like `var old = to; to = setTimeout(function() { clearTimeout(old); /* insert real stuff here */ }, 1000)` inside your `fs.watch`. The function then would fire only once, if the file keeps changing within the 1000 ms...

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way I can do now, thanks!